# Why firebase persistence does not save?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, persistence

I am trying to set persistence in my Angular project, but the data is not saving. Here admin can choose persistence mode in admindashboard.html

```
 <div class="inline">
    <h3>Choose persistence mode:</h3>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPersistence" (ngModelChange)="chosenPersistence()">
        <option>local</option>
        <option>session</option>
        <option>none</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then function in admindashboard.ts file is called

```
chosenPersistence() {
this.auth.changePersistenceMode(this.selectedPersistence);}
```

and finally function in auth.service is called

```
  persistenceSetting: string = 'local'; //variable to store persistence mode

  changePersistenceMode(mode: string): void{
    switch(mode){
      case "local":
        console.log(mode);
        this.afAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        this.persistenceSetting = "local"
        break
      case "session":
        console.log(mode);
        this.afAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        this.persistenceSetting = "session"
        break
      case "none":
          console.log(mode);
          this.afAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
          this.persistenceSetting = "none"
          break
    }
  }
```

Why is persistence mode not changing?